# React - styled components constructor from variable

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Is there a way to pass the return of another variable to the styled constructor "styled(xx)"?

I get an error:  Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, render, propTypes}).

```
import styled from 'styled-components/macro';
import { Link as LinkR } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Link as LinkS } from 'react-scroll';

const Link = props => (props.scroll ? LinkS : LinkR);

export const BtnContainer = styled(Link)`
    margin: 16px 0;
    padding: 16px 22px;
`
```

If I wrap the imported Link objects into `` or '' in the Link variable, it only outputs the return to the DOM. Ok, I expected that. :) But it shows me that something can be passed on to the constructor.

Wrapping in {} or $ {} do not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning the rendered link components?

```
const Link = (props) => props.scroll ? <LinkS {...props} /> : <LinkR {...props} />;
```

This makes `Link` an actual component and styled-components can handle them

Comment: Thanks, yes that is a good idea. I will try it tomorrow.